# Is it possible to change what cryptocurrency a defi protocol uses without hard forking?

Tags: dapps, defi, protocol

For example, let's say a defi staking protocol uses exclusively USDC token, but it decides to use another stablecoin instead, like Tether. Is there any way to smoothly translate all the assets staked on the platform from USDC to Tether? Or do you just have make an entirely different protocol? Is there a way to prepare for this contingency using Openzeppelin Upgradeability?

Comment: You could provide the users a proxy smart contract to interact with the staking protocol's core contracts. This has some drawbacks like increasing the potential for rugpulls and other abuse, and reducing the trust of users.

Comment: @kfx I apologize. I have a very limited technical knowledge, so I only vaguely understand how creating proxy contracts could solve the issue. Would I be using a different crypto asset for the proxy and another different crypto asset for the core? Also, how would this arrangement increase the potential for rugpulls? As I understand it, rugpulls are exclusive to governance tokens or similar tokens made by developers, no?